# need an if else for regex

Tags: regex

I have this regex to extract the name of a chatter in my iRC channel along with date and message capture groups

```
^\[(?:\d+)\-(?:\d+)(?:\-\d+) @ (\d+):\d+(?::\d+).\d+ (?:GMT|BST)\] (([^:]+)|\[[^\]]): ((?!\!).*)
```

it works on this chat line, it will work to give me 'bearwolf3' which is what I want as the 2nd capture group

```
[04-04-2017 @ 12:45:39.204 BST] bearwolf3: Break Fast
```

But if this line shows, I want to be able to extract a name of 'bladey2k14' from a relayed IRC message from my bot if it contains [ and ]

```
[04-04-2017 @ 12:45:22.338 BST] loonycrewbot: [bladey2k14]: tyt romani :)
```

so the 2nd capture would be 'bladey2k14'

I've seen if/then/else examples but it is not working for me to use and making my brain hurt!

can anyone modify my regex at the top to do this?

you can see it [here](https://regex101.com/r/7Ps2lA/3) . I want match 2 to have group 2 as bladey2k14 and group 3 as the message 'tyt romani'

Comment: If it is PCRE, you may use [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/7Ps2lA/1).

Comment: thanks, that appears to work in the tester. I will try it in the code. thanks a lot  @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: I'm sorry, I said 3rd group not 2nd. I've edited my question and added a link to regex101 to show the chat log and matches . 2nd match group 2 should be the username. would you mind taking a look @WiktorStribiżew?

Comment: What is your regex flavor? Not sure what you need, check https://regex101.com/r/rQdmPh/1

Comment: omg, that definitely appears to be working as it should @WiktorStribiżew . I will need to gather more chat logs because I've only just added the relay function that posts messages from users on a separate platform how can I thank you?

Comment: I will post then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try using the following expression:

```
^\[\d+-\d+-\d+ @ (\d+):\d+:\d+\.\d+ (?:GMT|BST)\] (?|([^:]+)(?!:\s*\[[^\]]*])|[^:]+:\s*\[([^\]]*)]): ([\w\s]*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rQdmPh/1)

The [branch reset group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html) `(?|...|...)` in a PCRE regex allows using different groups inside it with the same numbering offset. So, `(?|([^:]+)(?!:\s*\[[^\]]*])|[^:]+:\s*\[([^\]]*)])` will match `([^:]+)` and `([^\]]*)` will capture the values into Group 2.

I also removed unnecessary non-capturing groups (like in `(?:\d+)` - the groups are neither quantified, nor do they contain any alternation operators).

The parts I changed are `(?|([^:]+)(?!:\s*\[[^\]]*])|[^:]+:\s*\[([^\]]*)])` and `[\w\s]*`:

- `(?|([^:]+)(?!:\s*\[[^\]]*])|[^:]+:\s*\[([^\]]*)])` matches 1 of 2 alternatives:

  - `([^:]+)(?!:\s*\[[^\]]*])`: 1 or more chars other than `:` captured into Group 2 (with `([^:]+)`) not followed with `:`, 0+ whitespaces, `[`, 0+ chars other than `]` and `]` (with the negative lookahead `(?!:\s*\[[^\]]*])`)
  - `|` - or
  - `[^:]+:\s*\[([^\]]*)]` - 1+ chars other than `:`, followed with `:`, 0+ whitespaces, `[`, 0+ chars other than `]` captured into (again) Group 2, and then `]`.

The `[\w\s]*` matches 0+ chars that are letters/digits/`_`/whitespace.

Comment: Sorry, something is wrong with either my mouse, or SO scripts, I can hardly edit the answer any further.